# "The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 10.3) on the Mac Unnamed Server (...) is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS (version 10.4)"

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

On my Windows box I have VS 2017, and on my Mac I have Xamarin Studio 6.2.

When I try to build an iOS project in Visual Studio on Windows, it complains that "The installed Xamarin.iOS (version 10.3) on the Mac Unnamed Server () is not compatible with the local Xamarin.iOS (version 10.4)".

However, in Help -> About in VS, it reports that the Xamarin.iOS is version 10.4.0.123. On the Mac, Xamarin Studio reports that I have version 10.4.0.128. Presumably, these should be compatible. I have tried to check for updates, as noted in other questions, but there are none available.

Any hints as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those versions are not in fact compatible. Xamarin builds for VS 2017 are currently 1 build behind those for the Mac. I recommend downgrading your Mac Xamarin iOS Version to 10..4.0.123, which you can get from the your Xamarin account Downloads page:
https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads#all-versions

Get the 10.4 version dated Feb 28th (or perhaps Mar 1 depending on your time zone) which is version 10.4.0.123 as installed in your VS 2017.

See this release note for more info:
https://releases.xamarin.com/category/xamarin-for-visual-studio/

and note this line in the above:

> Do note that at the moment, Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017 is one build behind the version for Visual Studio 2015.

and thus is one build behind for Xamarin Studio on the Mac as well. So you can either downgrade your Mac to a matching version or go back to VS 2015.

Comment: If you need to use XCode 8.33, see this guide: https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-3-support-for-vs-2017/. You can now update to a build compatible with the latest stable of Xamarin.iOS on the Mac and get support of XCode 8.3.