# VS 2019 - Xamarin.iOS SDK version that is installed on Mac is (newer) not compatible with this version of VS (but VS 2022 is compatible)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

There are [older questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43009037/199364) on this topic, but I'd like to get advice on the current situation.

Details:

1. VS 2019 gives the message in the title. Even though it was recently updated, it still uses Xamarin.iOS 15.2.0.17, vs Mac's recent update to 15.4.0.0, to support the recent XCode update.
2. VS 2022 PREVIEW works - though its version says 15.3.0.41.

Question:

Is there a way to get VS 2019 to use the updated Xamarin.iOS? I assume the issue is that this is only on PREVIEW channel, but now that 2019 isn't the latest VS, I don't know how to give 2019 a preview version of Xamarin.iOS.

(I'd rather not do the alternative, which is to downgrade the version on the Mac.)

---

ALTERNATIVE: I could also install VS 2022 stable, if it is easier to get that to work with current XCODE + Xamarin.iOS. (I prefer to do certain tasks in a stable VS, not the PREVIEW one.)

(The reason I'm not using VS 2022 stable for my production VS, is that I uninstalled it while trying to solve a problem involving WinUI3 (Windows Desktop app) launch profiles in 2022 Preview - I was making 100% sure that there was only one version of 2022 involved. Probably didn't have anything to do with that issue, so I'm fine with re-installing it, if there is a good reason to do so.)

Comment: NOTE: I've since moved to VS 2022. On both PC and mac. No problems. I recommend 2022 now to anyone working with Xamarin.iOS, or Xamarin.Forms targetting iOS.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get VS 2019 to use the updated Xamarin.iOS?

ADAIK , there is no other way except updating `visual studio for windows`.

The latest Visual studio provides the latest package (Xamarim.iOS), if visual studio 2019 can't do that it means that it's time to use visual studio 2022 .

---

BTW , we can install latest `Xamarin.iOS` package without updating IDE in `visual studio for mac` , but it only works on mac.

Go to [Xamarin.iOS github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios) and download the pkg file ,install on mac .

[image]

Comment: This is annoying however, as of a couple of days ago VS 2022 is in release mode.  22 and 19 can run side by side on same machine.  Like you I don't want to downgrade the Mac.  I just hope the implications of the update aren't major.  Will comment more when done.

Comment: Had the same issue (same versions noted above) - was trying to do my Uno Platform (Xamarin native) dev on Visual Studio 2019. Simply running it in the latest GA version of VS 2022 (17.0.4) took care of the Xamarin iOS mismatch with my Mac.

Comment: Circling back on this.  I migrated to VS2022 without any issues, a pleasant surprise.  All now builds and deploys to app store.